# InvalidOperationException (sometimes) when getting keyboard state

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to get the keyboard state in my XNA application with the following code:

```
this.OldKeyboard = this.NewKeyboard;
this.NewKeyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
this.OldMouse = this.NewMouse;
this.NewMouse = Mouse.GetState();
```

However, *sometimes* (I think about 60%) when I start my game, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

```
An invalid operation occurred when trying to query the keyboard state.
The result code was 126.

at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex playerIndex)
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keyboard.GetState()
at GameLib.GameBase.Update(GameTime gameTime) in MY_PATH\GameLib\GameLib\GameBase.cs:Line 58.
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
at ...
```

My searches on google and SO did not give me any results on this code.

What could be the cause for this and why doesn't it occur everytime or never, but only sometimes when starting the project?

Edit: My thread layout:

- Main thread
- starts `Game.Run`
- starts a network initializer in a separate project (in `Initialize`)
- which starts a new thread for network I/O

When creating a new project only containing `Keyboard.GetState()`, I apparently get an error code of `0`, which translates to

> ERROR_SUCCESS
>
> 0 (0x0)
>
> The operation completed successfully.

See my screenshot below, I do not know why a success would trigger an `InvalidOperationException`.

[image: error code zero]

Comment: are you executing that code in the main thread? becuase it's needed.. you should execute that code in the update method

Comment: @Blau: yes, I am calling this in the Update method of a game I start in my `Main` method as usual. However, I am creating a network thread at some point in `Game.Initialize`, could this be the reason for the error? If yes, how would I start another thread without this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how old this thread is, but I heard it has something to do with your firewall. The same error happened to me when I updated my antivirus (do you happen to use Comodo?) Anyway, check that out, and see if it helps. It has nothing to do with XNA, I tested in visual c# express, visual studio 2012, and 2013, with same results, then I tried with a fresh project that only called the keyboard state, and it happened again. And none of that happened before I updated the antivirus...

Comment: I just checked with my firewall turned off and it seems to work. You are right, I am using Comodo. It was quite late, but thank you for your answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

`Keboard.GetState` uses the win32 function `GetKeyboardState` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx)) internally. If that fails, it gives an error code from [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx), which XNA fetches and packs into that exception for you.

That error code translates to: "The specified module could not be found."

Where "module" basically means DLL. And "not found" might refer to the DLL being loaded, or a DLL that *it*, in turn, requires (and so on). It's an extremely unhelpful error message.

I'm not really sure what DLL `GetKeyboardState` might be trying to load, or why it might fail intermittently.

Probably the first step to try and fix this would be to create a new, blank project and see if you get the same result, so you can figure out if it's your code, or something wrong with your system or XNA install.

(I imagine actually debugging this properly might involve using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to catch what DLL it is failing to load.)

Also, Blau is correct - all input in XNA must be done on the main thread.

Comment: Copying into a new project still gives the same error. Please also see my edit for the thread layout of the project.

Comment: how would I use process monitor for this? there are 1575 entries with `ProcessName == XNAGame.exe && Result != SUCCESS`, which ones are important for my problem?

Comment: I don't mean copying your code into a new project, I mean calling `Keyboard.GetState` from a fresh, otherwise-blank project, on your system - to see whether it's your code or your system that is at fault. As far as process monitor goes - that is really beyond what I can explain in a comment - although I was thinking more along the lines of searching for failure to read a DLL file. Consider asking a fresh question about how to debug win32 error 126 (and why `GetKeyboardState` might trigger it). The win32 experts here might have better insight.

Comment: a new project gives me error code `0` (success !?), please see my edit and the screenshot. why would windows throw an exception when it succeeds?

Comment: @csharpler I have absolutely no idea, I'm afraid. I'd definitely ask a fresh question with a `win32` tag - you might get better insights (link back here, of course, for context). My guess is that the `0` means that `GetKeyboardState` is failing and not setting an error (weird), or something else is setting an error of 0 in-between the failure and the call to `GetLastError` (weirder). At this stage I'd be investigating what my options are for debugging all the way into the `GetKeyboardState` method (disassembly, if need be).

Comment: At least at this stage we know it's something to do with your system or your Visual Studio setup. Try other combinations to narrow it down further: Debug vs Release build, inside vs outside Visual Studio, your exe on someone else's system (or a fresh VM), someone else's build of that code on your system. Also might be worthwhile seeing if you have anything "strange" running (malware or other software that could mess with the keyboard).