# GetKeyboardState returns error codes 126 and 0

Tags: winapi, module, xna, keyboard, getlasterror

I am creating an XNA game, in which I am calling `Keyboard.GetState()` which translates to the native method `GetKeyboardState()`.

This call throws an exception with error code 126 in my game, which translates to `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`.

When I create a new XNA project containing only `Keyboard.GetState()`, I get the error code 0 (`ERROR_SUCCESS`).

This appears not to be the case when building in Release Mode.

Note: This is a followup question on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010103/invalidoperationexception-sometimes-when-getting-keyboard-state), because this is more about the [win32](/questions/tagged/win32) calls than my programming.